# Resize docked widgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I have a main window of my app and two other widgets, that are docked to the right side of the main window. How could I resize the two docked widgets?
[image]

"Date" and "Time" widgets must be resized so that they both vertically take half of the space, and horizontally must be both wider.

Here is how I create the window and the widgets:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.resize(2000, 1200)
    self.center()
    self.setWindowTitle("ARMS")

    self.date = QDockWidget("Date", self)
    self.time = QDockWidget("Time", self)

    self.dateWidget = QWidget()

    self.timeWidget = QListWidget()
    self.timeWidget.addItems(['0', '3', '6', '9', '12', '15', '18', '21'])

    self.date.setWidget(self.dateWidget)
    self.date.setFloating(False)

    self.time.setWidget(self.timeWidget)
    self.time.setFloating(False)

    self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())
    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.date)
    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.time)
```

I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
self.date.resize(800, 1000) 
# and
self.dateWidget.resize(800, 1000)
```

Also, is there a way to make those two widgets undraggable and unclosable; just lock them at place the way they are?

Comment: [QMainWindow.resizeDocks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks) and [QDockWidget.setFeatures](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#features-prop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ekhumoro,

[QMainWindow.resizeDocks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks) and [QDockWidget.setFeatures](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#features-prop) are the answer.